# Single Abstract Method Equivalent to a Trait?

Tags: scala

Consider this trait:

```scala
trait Foo {
  def m1(id : Int) : Try[String]
}
```

And an instance of this:

```
  val g : Foo = new Foo {
    override def m1(id: Int): Try[String] = Success("Good job")
  }
```

Intellij offered a suggestion that this could converted to a Single Abstract Method:

```scala
  val g : Foo = (id: Int) => Success("Good job")
```

Are these two equivalent and how?

Comment: I think they produce slightly different bytecode (the second is a bit more efficient I think, using `invokedynamic` directly). Functionally, they'll do the same thing though.

Comment: Also see (if you haven't): https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types

Comment: This is the same as functional interfaces in Java. Won't be surprised if this compiles to the same bytecode as a java functional interface object would

Comment: Hey @M.K. Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Lets check what the `scalac` do for:

```
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

trait Foo {
  def m1(id : Int) : Try[String]
}

object MainClass {
  val g : Foo = new Foo {
    override def m1(id: Int): Try[String] = Success("Good job")
  }
}
```

run:

```
$ scalac -print src/main/scala/MainClass.scala
```

and output:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // MainClass.scala
package <empty> {
  abstract trait Foo extends Object {
    def m1(id: Int): scala.util.Try
  };
  object MainClass extends Object {
    private[this] val g: Foo = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def g(): Foo = MainClass.this.g;
    def <init>(): MainClass.type = {
      MainClass.super.<init>();
      MainClass.this.g = {
        new <$anon: Foo>()
      };
      ()
    }
  };
  final class anon$1 extends Object with Foo {
    override def m1(id: Int): scala.util.Try = new scala.util.Success("Good job");
    def <init>(): <$anon: Foo> = {
      anon$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

And do the same steps for:

```
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

trait Foo {
  def m1(id : Int) : Try[String]
}

object MainClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val g : Foo = (id: Int) => Success("Good job")
  }
}
```

run:

```
$ scalac -print src/main/scala/MainClass.scala
```

output:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // MainClass.scala
package <empty> {
  abstract trait Foo extends Object {
    def m1(id: Int): scala.util.Try
  };
  object MainClass extends Object {
    private[this] val g: Foo = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def g(): Foo = MainClass.this.g;
    final <artifact> private[this] def $anonfun$g$1(id: Int): scala.util.Try = new scala.util.Success("Good job");
    def <init>(): MainClass.type = {
      MainClass.super.<init>();
      MainClass.this.g = {
        ((id: Int) => MainClass.this.$anonfun$g$1(id))
      };
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see they are not the same for compiler.

In the first case, it is an anonymous object in second it is an anonymous function.